# How to lay stretch film around a frame so that it can hold water without leaks?

Tags: waterproofing

In order to store rain water and use it for the garden I need to build a 1000L water tank with custom dimensions (0,70m x 0,84m x 1,50m) made out of stretch film. So far I am experimenting with a smaller version (380 L) to decrease the plastic film waste during experiments.

This [page](https://ca-ressemble-a-du-fake.github.io/recuperateur_d_eau_en_film_etirable/) shows the project goal. Please note that the page is not updated to the latest experiments, it is just to show the goal. The final objective is to create a guide for anybody to reproduce it.

According to different experiments that I conducted earlier stretch film (22 micro meter thick) can hold the water pressure with several layers. The number of layers was computed as follows : 1,5m  of water creates a pressure of 15kPa on the lowest part of the tank and a single layer can hold experimentally 8kPa (5 kg on a 63 cm^2 area) so 2 layers would be enough and with a safety coefficient of 2, 4 layers will be wrapped.

So far I have made different wrapping experiments but there are always leaks from the bottom, expect for the first experiment (that is shown on the video). Yet I had to destroy this first wrapping and start again from scratch because of a hole that I created to insert a tap that was a catastrophe (big leaks).

I have laid the stretch film horizontally, vertically, with a cross shape at the bottom but there are still leaks often from the bottom edges or from the lower parts of the side walls sometimes with only a few liters of water (like 2 L), sometimes with hundreds of liters (like 300 L max). The film never breaks or explodes but the layers slowly separate from each other and the water starts to flow.

For the bottom part I first created a flange of stretch film from the side to the bottom (20 cm on the side, 25 cm under the bottom for a 45 cm wide film) and many turns (~ 10) around it. I thought that with the water weight that would compress the layers it would prevent the water from leaking out of the bottom part. Note that the leaks are several drops per second enough to let the soil wet.

Consequently I am looking for wrapping methods / theory (if any) or advises to lay the stretch film layers around the rectangular parallelepiped frame (sides and bottom are rectangular) that would create a waterproof wall.

Comment: Just use the wrap for strength and line the inside with a single undamaged sheet.

Comment: `tank with specific dimensions` ... it makes more sense to say the dimensions instead

Comment: Thanks @jsotola I added the dimensions. "specific dimensions" should be understood in the following way : "dimensions that match specific needs of mine (ie not available on the market)".

Comment: that's `custom dimensions` ... the thing is that the depth of the tank is very important to know because it defines the pressure that is exerted on the film at the bottom

Comment: Thank you @SolarMike. `single sheet` will be hard with the wrap film I have because each frame direction (width, height, depth) is larger than sheet width (45 cm). Correct me if I misunderstood your suggestion but the wrap film has to be very wide (2 x 1,70 m) to cover the whole height in a single layer. Not sure it would be easy to handle such a big layer.

Comment: @jsotola That's correct. I added the calculus I used to find the number of layer to be wrapped around the frame and hold that pressure. So far the wrap film never broke or tore apart only some outer layers stretched more than the inner layers and let the water infiltrate. On this [video](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/6NzSC4k_n9Q?feature=share) the film did not break. That's why I think the wrapping needs improvements.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by [@DKNguyen](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54849/can-i-weld-stretch-film#comment104402_54849) painter's plastic film did the trick. 4m x 5m plastic film (LDPE, 7 µm) is very cheap and makes things much easier. I will detail every step in my blog post.

To sum it up I "sandwiched" this plastic film between two sheets of stretch film and then I wrapped the 10 layers around to stiffen the whole thing.

Yet the 7 µm thick plastic film is very fragile (a hole on an edge quickly appeared), so I also bought a 30 µm thick 4m x 5m plastic film (~ 10€) but haven't had the need for it so far (there are no leaks until now).